# Singleton in swift is not accessible from another class

Tags: swift, singleton

I am new to Swift and am trying to access a 'problemSolved' array that is appended during gameplay in my main GameController class, from another class. For some reason the array is not visible in a UIViewController class where I want to show all the problems solved in a table. I have read many of the Singleton examples on the site to see if this will do it, but that doesn't seem to. Any help or advice here much appreciated!

```
class GameController: TileDragDelegateProtocol, CenterViewControllerDelegate {
   static let sharedInstance = GameController()
   var problemsSolved = Array<String>()  

   func onProblemSolved() {
     problemsSolved.append(problem)
     println("problemsSolved contains \(problemsSolved)")
}
}
```

During gameplay I can see in the console that the array is being appended ok in GameController. But when I try to access it in a ViewController class the contents are showing as empty [].

```
class SidePanelViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
tableView.reloadData()
println("the array viewed from here is empty \(GameController.sharedInstance.problemsSolved)")

}
```

Comment: Where does the variable "problem" come from which you append to the array?

Comment: Hi Qbyte, the game is a word matching game. In GameController there is a func dealWord() that pulls a word from a 'words' Array in a Level Class. (I seem to be able to access from GameController ok, but not too GameController, hence this problem!). Once the func dealWord() finishes there func onProblemSolved that checks if the problem is solved with an if else statement, and if so adds the word to the problemSolved Array. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment I only can imagine that you don't call

```
GameController.sharedInstance.onProblemSolved()
```

when you want to append a String to `problemsSolved`.

You should also consider making your functions and variables in `GameController` static.

If this doesn't solve your problem I would need more information about how and when you add something to `problemsSolved`.

Comment: brilliant Qbyte, that was indeed my mistake. Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome! Could you mark the answer as "right"? So other people can see your question as solved.